# UIView shows immedialtelly after loading NIB-file?

Tags: ios, uiview, nib, addsubview

i try to add a UIView to my application. it does work but not as expected. i´ve defined the socialActionView in my header and made a @synthesize in my view controller.

the nib-file is loaded when the user tabs a button. i thought i have to call the addSubview-method to show the view. but it shows up even i i don´t do it.

if i call the addSubView-method anyway the app crashes when i load the view with the message "warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame."

can anybody explain what´s goning on here? i don´t understand that.

```
- (IBAction)didTapOkSocialAction:(id)sender;
{
    self.socialActionView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SocialActionViewController" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    //[self.view addSubview:socialActionView];
}
```

EDIT

in this case the solution was to set the file´s owner of my SocialActionViewController.xib to ViewController.h. i don´t know yet how to add a UIView from NIB attached to another view controller class than the view controller where the view is loaded into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `socialActionView` is already bound to the view placeholder in its superview.

So: its already there (its reference is already added as a subview) but it is `nil` until you actually load it.

EDIT: it's not clear how you have everything connected there, but from your added info below i'll take a wild guess.

Try this code:

```
- (IBAction)didTapOkSocialAction:(id)sender;
{
    UIView *loadedView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SocialActionViewController" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    [self.view addSubview:loadedView];
}
```

EDIT: since you want to programatically load a viewcontroller from .xib you can do it like so (supposably viewcontroller is defined in MyViewController.h,.m,.xib):

```
MyViewController *myViewController;  //as an ivar or a property in @interface


myViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
```

then you can add it's view:

```
[self.view addSubview: myViewController.view];
```

Comment: ah i see. i assumed already something like that. but even if i change it to this:

UIView *socialActionView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SocialActionViewController" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    
it still shows the UIView immediatelly. is that the usual behavior? i´m just wondering for what the addSubView is useful if it´s not needed anymore?

Comment: @rockstarberlin: You'd probably be better off loading it immediately with `hidden` property set to `YES` and just unhide it when user taps the button. But that depends on your app's structure and hierarchy so i really couldn't say.

Comment: @rockstarberlin: Of course addSubview is still needed, just in other cases. As for your second test: it is strange - compiler should at least issue a warning - if you have property and local variable with same name.

Comment: hm, yes perhaps you´re right. i thought it´s better practice to load stuff not until it´s needed. thank you for your answer.

Comment: ok, wait. i load it first on user interaction. until that the nib isn´t loaded. so it should still be fine

Comment: Yes you'll still be fine with your code (without extra `addSubView`). It's just a little more complicated than it could be :)

Comment: i just made some more experiments. i had some other confusing experiences with the socialActionView. and then i found out that my socialActionView is not put on top of the current view but it replaces it completely. i´ve set the alpha of socialActionView to 0.5 and have seen that my former view dissapeared! how can that be? what´s wrong with my structure? or isn´t it possible to add a subveiw programatically on top of the current view?

Comment: Of course it is possible. But in that case something else is going on that is not visible from a description in your question. Is socialActionView also connected to some view in .XIB file (trough IBAction) - i need more details on how everything is set up.

Comment: step by step i find out more. what i tried is to have a dedicated view controller for loadNibNamed called SocialActionViewController. what i didn´t know is that controllers are completely ignored if i load a nib with loadNibNamed. i was wondering to what the owner:self is referencing. and it seems that it is not possible to reference to something else than self. in another post i red that if i load with loadNibNamed only the view is loaded. there are no contoller classes attached and therefore not executed.

Comment: i tried to attach properties in IB to the view to reference a scrollView but that didn´t help cause the contoller was ignored. then i defined the properties in the MainView and - oh wonder - it worked. even if i´ve attached the scrollView in my SocialActionView.xib to a variable called scroll1 in SocialActionViewController. it seems that IB made anyway a connection to the ViewController. Now i´ve deleted SocialActionViewController.h and SocialActionViewController.m and set the Class of SocialActionView to ViewController and definde the properties there.

Comment: And now i have to call [self.view addSubview:socialActionView]; to show the view. Everything works fine. I´m only wondering how can i put a view on top of my current view which should have it´s own view controller?

Comment: Hope you find the solution - at this point it's hard if not impossible to see what your current configuration is and what exactly you want to achieve. It would be best if you organize this additional information and update your question with it.

Comment: yes i did. thank you! the only question left is how can i add an UIView which has it´s own UIViewController?

Comment: In that case you have to instantiate the second viewController (and keep reference to it in an ivar or as a property) and add it's view to the first viewController's view.

Comment: ok, thanks rokjarc. that´s what i wanted to do. i have to find some examples for that as it seems that loading from nib does load only view contend and ui elements but no controllers as i would need it.

Comment: that´s it! thanks a lot! i did that a time ago once but forgot how it was done properly and was only looking for how to load a nib. but that was the wrong approach. instantiating the viewController is it!

Answer (score 2):

if i create a UIView programatically like this

```
- (IBAction)didTapOkSocialAction:(id)sender;
{
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100)];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
    [myView release];
}
```

then the addSubView is inevitable. otherwise myView would not appear. i´ve tested that. but it seems that there is a different behaviour if the UIView is loaded from a nib. it shows up immediately.

in the second test i´ve deleted the property, there was only the local variable left.